# How to make JDialog top-most but not modal?

Tags: java, applet, jdialog

I'm creating an applet. That applet has to take some big chunks of data from the db and that operation is slow... That's why I would like to create a "loading" JDialog that will be shown on top of the applet while the applet is loading data from the DB, BUT it shouldn't block user input to applet.
How to do it? If I create a JDialog that is "setAlwaysOnTop(true)" it won't show on top. If I set it to modal it will show but it won't allow my applet to communicate with DB. I even tried to make that "loading" window runnable and run it from another thread, no luck.

How to make proper, universal, "loading" JDialog for applet that WON'T be modal, but will stay always on top?

Answer (score 2):

It is generally a very (and i mean very very) bad idea to call swing/awt
 from a non EDT thread. Be awere, there are numerous issues with how applet JFrame/JDialog work in OSX and Windows. IMO it would make for much better user experience if your applet just used `JProgressBarr` or something in your applets UI directly. If you absolutely have to pop up a window, use JFrame with `AlwaysOnTop=true`. The reason you are getting weird behavior is that you probably not using constructor that takes parent component or simply pass in a `null` value.

Comment: That's true, i'm not passing parent to "super" but it seems i can't cause JDialog doesn't have a constructor that takes Applet as a parent...

Comment: true but you can use something like this `new JDialog(SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(yourJapplet))`. I don't see why you have to use JDialog though, it is not like you need modality or anything.

Comment: I need to use it cause i'm refactoring existing and VERY complicated applet (it's like a standalone app for managing betting database) so i can't change it totally and it has to remain as applet :)